# How to get RSS feeds for custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I want separate feed of each custom post type so that I can utilise it in mobile apps. Most of the resources on the web describe the same thing to do as:

```
www.your-website.com/feed/?post_type=custom_post_type_name
```

I tried this but it generates same feed for all post types that includes all posts and page. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This article has helped me achieve this on several websites in the past.

> http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-make-a-separate-rss-feed-for-each-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/

Also it may not always be necessary but adding this to `functions.php` adds RSS links to the header of your website.

```
// Add RSS feed links to head.
add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plug-in for that.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-rss-feed/
```

Comment: It just lists the url of custom post type feeds in head of the page. But when I open each URl, content is always same and undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add to your functions.php the following filter:

```
function my_custom_feed($qv) {
  if (isset($qv['feed']))
      $qv['post_type'] = get_query_var('post_type');
  return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'my_custom_feed');
```

this way you are changing the post showing into feeds, from your standard post to custom post type defined in query parameters